# How do I create deciles at the school-level using student-level data?

Tags: stata

I am trying to create a school-level learning inequality index based on the difference in learning outcomes between the top 10% and the bottom 50% of students in each school. The data are student-level (below is my attempt) but evidently, I am not creating the deciles at the school level. I imagine I need to use a foreach loop, but that is not yet something I know am fluent at.

My attempt:

```
bysort IDSCHOOL: egen pv__std_deciles = std(avg_pv)
xtile pv_deciles=avg_pv, nq(10)
bysort IDSCHOOL: egen school_pv_5 = mean(avg_pv) if pv_deciles<6 
bysort IDSCHOOL: egen school_pv_10 = mean(avg_pv) if pv_deciles==10
egen max_sp_10=max(school_pv_10), by(IDSCHOOL)
egen max_sp_5=max(school_pv_5), by(IDSCHOOL)
gen school_pv_diff= max_sp_10 - max_sp_5
sort IDSCHOOL
quietly by IDSCHOOL: gen dup = cond(_N == 1, 0, _n)
drop if dup > 1
isid IDSCHOOL
```

Comment: Sorry, but what is the precise question? Does your code not work at all or not give the right results? Without a data example, it is hard to see what might be wrong just by skimming the code.

Comment: My code doesn't give me the right results. When I create the deciles, it uses the average score of each student across all schools. I rather need to create deciles using the average score of each student within each school.

Comment: That helps; thanks. But presumably your starting point is an identifier for each student and your code doesn't appear to use one or to tell us what that is.